# api request for login adobe connect in php

Tags: php, request, adobe-connect

im try the request api for login in adobe connect until the my user don't need to login and automatic go to class link,i according the adobe connect use 2 way to request but I went right until the end but go to class link ,redirect to login page
i do not know my problem

text in adobe connect for login:

Log in to an Adobe Connect hosted account with an account ID
1 Before you log the user in, call common-info with the domain name of your Adobe Connect hosted account in either the request URL or the domain parameter:
http://acme.adobe.com/api/xml?action=common-info http://adobe.com/api/xml?action=common-info&domain=acme.adobe.com
Last updated 9/4/2013
 USING ADOBE CONNECT 9 WEB SERVICES 12 Login and requests
2 Parse the response for the values of cookie and account-id:
   Sbreezzd2dfr2ua5gscogv
   ...
   
3 Collect the user’s login ID and password in your application.
4 Call the login action, adding the user’s credentials and the account-id and session parameters:
https://example.com/api/xml?action=login&login=joy@acme.com &password=happy&account-id=295153&session=Sbreezzd2dfr2ua5gscogv
5 Parse the response for a status code of ok.
6 (Optional) If you prefer, you can call login before common-info, extract the cookie value from the response
header, and manage it yourself or using a cookie management library.

```
$class_link = "http://185.50.145.230/academy9"

$response = file_get_contents("http://185.53.140.234/api/xml?action=common-info");

$result = simplexml_load_string($body);
$value = $result->common->cookie;
$session = (string)$value;

$account = $result->common->account->attributes()->{'account-id'};
$account_id = (int)$account;
$link = "https://185.50.145.230/api/xmlaction=login&login=alinadi14@gmail.com&password=123456&accountid=".$account_id."&session=".$session;
$response2 = file_get_contents($link);

$_SESSION['BREEZESESSION'] = $session;
header("Set-Cookie: BREEZESESSION=".$session);
header("Location: ". $class_link);
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I found your question and it helped me to login to Adobe Connect with PHP. I have solved your problem by passing the session parameter to the meeting URL.
Surely you would already find the problem, but I write it in case it helps someone.
Greetings

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://serverconnect/api/xml?action=common-info");
$result = simplexml_load_string($response);
$session = $result->common->cookie;    
    
$link_login = "https://serverconnect/api/xml?action=login&login=user@email.com&password=1234&session=".$session;
$response2 = file_get_contents($link_login);    

 header("Location:  http://serverconnect/meetingurl/?session=".$session);
 die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Connect uses cookies to log in. `curl` library supports the cookies and can store them in a file.
The following function creates `.keep.cookie.log` file beside your PHP file and saves cookie info.
At the end of the function `simplexml_load_string` is used to parse the answer.

```
define('HOST_URL', 'http://255.255.255.255');

function AdobeConnectAPI($params)
{
    $cookie_file = __DIR__ . '/.keep.cookie.log';
    $ch = curl_init(HOST_URL . '/api/xml?' . http_build_query($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $output = simplexml_load_string($output) or die('Problem');
    return $output;
}
```

An example of using the `AdobeConnectAPI` function to reading the recording list of Adobe Connect for a specific session:

```
AdobeConnectAPI([
    'action' => 'login', 
    'login' => 'USERNAME', // your username
    'password' => 'PASSWORD' // your password
]);
    
$recordings_list = AdobeConnectAPI([
    'action' => 'sco-contents', 
    'sco-id' => 676501 // class sco-id
]);
    
AdobeConnectAPI([
    'action' => 'logout'
]);

foreach (((array)$recordings_list->scos)['sco'] as $recording) {
    echo HOST_URL . $recording->{'url-path'} . '<br>';
}
```